Load PDF from media server into iFrame ends with error in iPhone dev console
I tried to show PDF file inside frame window. Many approaches and ways but still same result:
Blocked a frame with origin "https://fe-url.com" from accessing a frame with origin "https://api.fe-url.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.
FE TypeScript APP is app domain.
From this domain I need to load file from media server (it is subdomain of app domain)
something like this:
test.com (app domain)
api.test.com/medias/pdfresizer.com-pdf-resize.pdf?context=bWFzdGVyfGF6dXJlaW1hZ2VzfDg1Nzc4N3xhcHBsaWNhdGlvbi9wZGZ8YUdJMkwyaGpNeTh4TWpNd01UTTRORE14T1RBd05pOXdaR1p5WlhOcGVtVnlMbU52YlMxd1pHWXRjbVZ6YVhwbExuQmtaZ3w5Y2M3MTQ5ZTY5YjFiZTJkNmExODg4ZGYyZjY0MjQ4MmI2NDgwNjhjY2FjYTIxY2YyNDI0OWMzYmFjODgwYTQz&attachment=false#navpanes=0&view=Fit&scrollbar=1&toolbar=0&statusbar=0 (media server)
But on iOS I still get error about blocked request.
Port and protocols are same.
The PDF sometimes shows sometimes not.
Web page is stuck when try to load PDF file.
Thanks for any advice.
I already tried:

ngx-doc-viewer (3rd party library)
<iframe> (pure HTML approach)
postMessage (this could works if the    source of iFrame will be
another    web app/page and I can set    message event handler) but
second side is rest-api media server    without FE/GUI.)

I expect that PDF file is loaded normally in iFrame without freeze the web page.

You need to include a code example, and a link to this running somewhere. Your question lacks enough detail to answer.
